# What is the symbol for Tangent Velocity?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

If the tangent space in a spacetime manifold is described using the symbol $T_pM$, where $M$ describes for the manifold, then what would be the symbol for the partial derivative of the tangent space with respect to proper time? That is, what would be the commonly accepted symbol for the tangent velocity ($\frac{\partial T_pM}{\partial \tau}$)?

Comment: Normally you differentiate a function, not a space and the tangent vector would be the span of a one dimensional tangent space. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Why can't I take the partial derivative of the tangent space with respect to time? The tangent space is the set of all possible vectors perpendicular to the surface of a manifold at a given point. The partial derivative with respect to time selects the tangent velocity which is just one of those possible vectors.

Comment: Because the space isn't a function. Once you have the tangent space there is no reason to calculate another partial derivative since you already have all the vectors in the space. Just pick one if you want one.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - If the space in my manifold is described by:$$\tau^2=t^2+x^2$$Then why can't I interpret the tangent velocity to be:$$\left(\frac{\partial T_PM}{\partial \tau}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}\right)^2$$As I understand it, $\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau}$ would then be the temporal tangent velocity and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}$ would be the (plain old) tangent velocity. Is there a common symbol for the plain old tangent velocity?

Comment: The tangent space *is* the tangent vector. I'm not sure why you think you have to find it again after finding it. Are you just trying to reconstruct a directional derivative from the total derivative? I would also point out that time and velocity are physics terms, not math terms so it's a little weird that you keep appealing to them. It's like asking how biologists name rocks, it's just not what they do.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - _"Are you just trying to reconstruct a directional derivative from the total derivative?"_ Yes. It seems to me that all the tangent vectors could be described with $V_\mu\equiv T_pM$, in which case, the tangent velocity (the specific vector with respect to the temporal basis vector, $e_\tau$) would be $V_\tau$. I think the term for which I'm looking is $V_\tau$, but I'm not sure. If you can figure out what I'm after and have better terms for it, I would appreciate the lesson.

Comment: So $T_p M$ has all the information about the tangent space encoded, including the point on the manifold where the tangent space can be thought of as the best linear approximation for the manifold at the point, just like a tangent line from first year calculus. However in differential geometry you're going to do a lot of work to avoid choosing a basis since you typically want to work in a way that every observer can agree on, which is coordinate-free. That includes the time coordinate as different observers will experience time differently.

Comment: The tangent space is the set of all possible vectors perpendicular to the surface of a manifold. Huh? Are you looking at a hypersurface in Lorentzian 4-space and wanting to differentiate the normal vector of that hypersurface?

Comment: @TedShifrin - _"Are you looking at a hypersurface in Lorentzian 4-space and wanting to differentiate the normal vector of that hypersurface?"_ Yes. specifically, a six dimensional manifold of constant acceleration, a.